# How to change the color of non-editable EditText cell

Tags: fonts, colors, android-edittext

I have a series of EditText cells that based on the user selection some will be auto-fill and then I change those EditText cells to non-editable by doing "myCell[x].setEnabled(false)". In this case the font color changes to gray which is not well readable. Is there a way to change color of the font of an EditText which has .setEnabled(false) or is there another way of disabling the cells from being editable with more control on the font type and color? I can change the background but rather not.

Comment: You might use a selector, to change the color of the enabled and disabled state.

Answer (score 2):

You can by using a selector:

`color/my_custom_edittext.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF0000" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="#0000FF"/>
</selector>
```

`layout/main_activity.xml`:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:textColor="@color/my_custom_edittext" />
```

It should solve your problem.